# How to declare common variables for all methods of a Django class-based view?

Tags: django, oop, django-views

I have a class-based view in my Django application and it works fine. But I guess it is not coded well, because it violates the DRY principle. Specifically, I have two absolutely similar declarations of the `posts_list` variable inside `get()` and `post()` methods:

```
class TopicView(View):
    def get(self, request, topic_id):
        post_form = PostForm()
        posts_list = Post.objects.filter(topic_id=self.kwargs['topic_id']).order_by('-creation_date')
        return render(request, 'discussions/topic.html', {'posts_list': posts_list,
                                                          'post_form': post_form,
                                                          'topic_id': topic_id})

    def post(self, request, topic_id):
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
            post.save()
            return redirect('discussions:topic', topic_id=topic_id)

        posts_list = Post.objects.filter(topic_id=self.kwargs['topic_id']).order_by('-creation_date')
        return render(request, 'discussions/topic.html', {'posts_list': posts_list,
                                                          'post_form': post_form,
                                                          'topic_id': topic_id})
```

Is there a way how I can declare this variable as a class attribute instead of a simple variable inside each of the methods? When I declaring it, I use `topic_id` as a filter for objects, and I extract `topic_id` from the URL (`self.kwargs` object, `self` is passed to both `get()` and `post()` as an input parameter). This is the main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can reorganize this.  But one simple way is to put the common code in its own method, then call it when you need it.. like so:

```
class TopicView(View):
    def get(self, request, topic_id):
        return self.post_list_response(PostForm())

    def post(self, request, topic_id):
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
            post.save()
            return redirect('discussions:topic', topic_id=topic_id)

        return self.post_list_response(post_form)

    def post_list_response(self, post_form):
        topic_id = self.kwargs['topic_id']
        posts_list = Post.objects.filter(topic_id=topic_id).order_by('-creation_date')
        return render(request, 'discussions/topic.html', {
            'posts_list': posts_list,
            'post_form': post_form,
            'topic_id': topic_id
        })
```

You could also structure this slightly better/differently by using Django's `FormView` class rather than just plain `View`.

Comment: Can I pass additional parameters to the template when using `FormView`? Namely, I mean `posts_list` variable which I need to have in my `topic.html` template.

Comment: Yes, with FormView, you can override FormView's `get_context_data` method to add your own context variables.   You don't call render yourself, FormView does that for you.

Comment: Let me add.. with a FormView you would not implement `get` or `post` methods you just need a `form_valid` method which contains the code you want to run when the form is valid.. and then you would extend `get_context_data` to add the code for your list